Problema al realizar un segundo filtro a la consulta principal - Eloquent Laravel
La idea es que me retorne datos dependiendo de los valores de la variables que reciba
  /**
     * Mostrar una lista filtrada de prendas.
     */
    public function index($genre, $type = NULL, $collection = NULL)
    {

        $query = Clothe::with(['brand', 'collection', 'gender', 'size', 'typeclothe'])
            ->whereHas('gender', function ($q) use ($genre) {
                $q->where('gender', $genre);
            });

        if ($type) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('typeclothe', function ($q) use ($type) {
                $q->where('type', $type);
            });
        }

        //dd($query);
        $clothes = $query->get();
        dd($clothes);
    }

No entiendo por que la variable $clothes queda vacia siendo que al hacer las comprobaciones con el metodo dd($) puedo corroborar que la variable $query contiene las colecciones filtradas, tambien quiero añadir que este problema solo ocurre cuando agrego el segundo filtro, es decir, si solo dejo la primer consulta:
$query = Clothe::with(['brand', 'collection', 'gender', 'size', 'typeclothe'])
        ->whereHas('gender', function ($q) use ($genre) {
            $q->where('gender', $genre);
        });

    //dd($query);
    $clothes = $query->get();
    dd($clothes);

puedo copiar la coleccion a la variable $clothes sin problemas, estoy pasandome de alto algo? estaria agradecida si me pueden dar una mano, saludos!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Para encontrar el error te sugiero obtener el código sql que eloquent lleva a la base de datos, esto lo puedes debuguear con la function ->ToSQL();
Acá una referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string
Además, si sigues sin encontrar la respuesta a tu pregunta, recuerda que puedes usar la función DB::raw('query') para ejecutar código puro de SQL como alternativa más directa a la base de datos.
Acá otra referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925451/how-can-i-query-raw-via-eloquent
Suerte!

Gracias por tu respuesta, lo hice pero no encontré error en la consulta, pero si me inspiro para seguir buscandolo por medio de sql y encontré el problema, estaba en la falta de datos coincidentes en mi base de datos para la consulta que estaba realizando. Específicamente, no tenía registros que coincidieran con los criterios de búsqueda que estaba utilizando, una vez que actualicé los datos en mi base de datos para que coincidieran con los filtros que estaba buscando, la consulta comenzó a funcionar, agradezco mucho su paciencia y las valiosas recomendaciones.

es por el get() al momento de igual.
prueba algo asi
    $query = Clothe::whereHas('gender', function ($q) use ($genre) {
            $q->where('gender', $genre);
        });

    if ($type) {
        $query = $query->whereHas('typeclothe', function ($q) use ($type) {
            $q->where('type', $type);
        });
    }

    //dd($query);
    $clothes = $query->with(['brand', 'collection', 'gender', 'size', 'typeclothe']);


Gracias por tu respuesta, si bien funciona, puedo ver que la variable $clothes ahora si tiene el contenido de $query, el problema es que al no usar get() esta variable no queda como una coleccion, por lo que al querer manejarla en las vistas ya no podria a traves de las funciones isEmpty(), empty(), etc , tendre que simplemente utilizar otras funcionalidades?
